# Weird admin area

Tags: wp-admin

Everything works fine but it looks weird and I'm worried.
See attached screen grab. Any ideas?

[image: screen grab]

Comment: This is probably styling that is injected by the theme you are using

Comment: That's exactly what it is, is there a solution?

Comment: It is impossible to say what the best solution is without knowing which theme you are using. Just a tip here, if your theme is a premium theme, you will need to ask the authors of the theme, as premium themes are off topic as we don't have any access to them.

Comment: I'm trying to build a theme. I fixed it by adding this to my functions; wp_register_style( 'main-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false, '1.0.0', 'all');

function enqueue_script_front_wpse_84975() {
  wp_enqueue_style('main-styles');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_script_front_wpse_84975'); Thanks for your help again!

Comment: You should at this an answer and score yourself some reputation